# Activator.CreateInstance throws ArgumentNullException for parameter 'Type'

Tags: asp.net, profile, web-deployment-project, activator

I recently encountered a problem with my Profile provider: it wouldn't retrieve profiles correctly (see error below). It worked locally, but when I put the code compiled by a Web Deployment project on a server it would crash.

> Value cannot be null.
>       Parameter name: type
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of
>       the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>       information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Strack Trace:**
>   [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: type]
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +2796915
>   System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.CreateMyInstance(String username, Boolean isAuthenticated) +76
>   System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Create(String username, Boolean isAuthenticated) +312

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

---

I found the solution, but it's far from being obvious (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my error was to **uncheck** this option from the Web Deployment project:

> Treat as library component (remove App_Code.Compiled file)

Answer (score 0):

Simply building the web deployment project again after the checkbox change is sometimes not sufficient.

You should rebuild the web site, or clean the ASP.NET temporary ASP.NET Files folder, usually located in "%WINDIR%Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files".

Answer (score 0):

I've recently experienced this problem and it turned out to be a missing dependency. Using the fuslogvw.exe tool provided with visual studio finally identified the problem.