# Profile Base GetProfile command throws null type in CreateInstance

Tags: web, profile

I am working on a web application that uses built-in security classes to create new users

newuser = MembershipUser.Create(relevant parameters)

that is all well and good

it then issues a Profile.GetProfile(newuser.UserName)
which drills down to a 
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

which throws a 
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

it works fine in dev (visual Studio 2015 Community)
the current site was developed on an older machine, probably Visual Studio 2010
and works just fine

why am I getting these errors - and how do I fix it?

Comment: this entry was the answer <br/>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926729/activator-createinstance-throws-argumentnullexception-for-parameter-type/45525273#45525273

Comment: it's doing this again - and the check mark is off - I have deleted the temporary files - this is supposed to be the solution not the problem

Comment: I found out that the problem was due to 2 different versions of Telerik Reporting - an earlier paid version in the GAC on the host machine and the trial version in the bin loaded on the development machine in order to compile the program